# Concurrent writes into Map containing another Map in Golang

Tags: go, concurrency

In Golang we have to sync concurrent changes to the Map. If my Map contains another Map like this:

```
map[string]map[string]*CustomStruct
```

.. do I have to use **Lock** in all of them when writing something?

If I'll write something into internal Map -> outer Map will also be changed, so I still have to sync outer Map's changes.

If I Lock outer Map's changes -> no one else can write into internal Map -> there is no point to Lock internal Map.

Am I right or it works in a different way and I must lock all Maps?

Comment: Just try it out under the race detector :-)  If you can ensure that no two code path write concurrently to the same inner map then you should be good. But why take a risk? What's wrong with a cute little mutex here or maybe several?

Comment: @Volker, I could add several locks, but I feel that useless lock/unlock is like unused variable - why does it exist?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that there aren't any hard and fast rules here.

For example, you could coordinate all map writes via a mutex that's not even stored on the map, there is no inherent link between any mutex and your map - its just about how you use them to coordinate access to your data.

Essentially if you lock individual elements you will see less contention over the locks because the locks will be acquired less often, if you use an outer lock over all maps there will be more contention as more processes will be trying to acquire the same lock which will reduce how much actual work your processes can get done.

It's ultimately up to you to work out what works best for your use case

**Help with that:**

There is a new tool available in go 1.9 that allows you to benchmark lock contention to see what approach is most efficient for your application.

Building and running your app with the `-race` flag will help determine if the locks are doing their job correctly

You could also take a look at the new sync maps which I haven't played with yet but I understand handle this for you:

[Sync maps](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map)

Comment: But changing internal Map will also change the outer Map - is that true? Because in general it is a one big Map. So I always will have to lock outer Map

Comment: short answer is that depends if you need to (can the outer map change?) - If the outer map will always be referring to the same inner maps then no you don't need to, if you are only ever adding new inner maps then you could just get a read lock (you can acquire multiple read locks). If there is a chance another process will delete the inner map from the outer map, or replace it with a different map, then yes you do

Comment: Might be helpful to think of the outer map as a map of pointers to the inner maps (which they are), as long as the pointers aren't changing you are good

Comment: My outer Map can always be changed, new entries appear and may be modified, some other disappear. So if I add new inner Map - I should lock the outer Map; if I modify the inner Map - I should lock only this inner Map; if I delete inner Map - outer Map should be locked?! Correct?

Comment: Unfortunately no, If there is a chance of deleting a map from the outer map I think you will always have to acquire a Write lock on the outer map when modifying the inner map other wise it may get deleted during modification. So for your purposes you may as well do away with the locks on the inner map and just lock the outer map every time you modify anything. If performance is an issue you might look at some way of batching together the changes or nesting the inner maps in a struct. you could then lock this struct when you modify or delete an inner map and periodically clean these up.

Answer (score 0):

The simple (and most likely good enough) solution is to have a mutex that protects the whole structure. It can be a regular mutex or a read-write mutex, in case reads are much more frequent than writes. This is easy to implement, easy to reason about and in the vast majority of cases it will do the job.

If on the other hand you're looking for a challenge, then you can take this into a number of directions:

- Have a top-level read-write mutex and one (simple or read-write) mutex per top-level map key. Write lock the top-level mutex when adding or deleting entries to the top level map; else read lock it, acquire the entry-specific lock and read or write the entry (which is also a map).
- Decide on what kind of parallelism you want and split your top-level map into shards, with keys sharded based on their hash and one mutex per shard. Then you can have parallel writes (key adds and removes) to multiple keys as long as they are in different shards.
- Apply the second approach to the second-level maps too. Go crazy! :o)

But, in all seriousness, unless this map is huge, much of your application is simply adding and removing stuff from it, and you're willing to put a lot of effort into benchmarking and tweaking your implementation, go with the single lock approach. It is actually going to be much faster in the general case and, as a bonus, it's simple to implement.